# Web forms delete button with bootstrap outside the form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I've got an issue. I want to create a delete button that will erase a record from database. As long as I know how to do everything with database, I have NO IDEA how to manage with the button. I use javaScript to create a table and fill it with records. HALP!

```
function CreateATableFromDataBase() {
            var deserializedData = '<%=serializedList %>';
            deserializedData = JSON.parse(deserializedData);
            for (var i = 0; i < deserializedData.length; i++) {
                document.write(
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<th scope=\"row\">" + i.toString() + "</th>" +
                    "<th>" + deserializedData[i]["Name"] + "</th>" +
                    "<th>" + deserializedData[i]["Where"] + "</th>" +
                    "<th>" + deserializedData[i]["Destination"] + "</th>" +
                    "<th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-primary\">Delete</button></th>" +
                "</tr>"
                );
            }
        }
```

I have a button yet I have no idea how to assign a method to it. Moreover, I've been thinking about routes.

I use Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this that comes to mind if you don't want to use normal ASP.NET Web Forms form and buttons is to use AJAX (jQuery makes it easier) and ASP.NET Web Methods.

You will need a way of identifying your buttons and passing some sort of identifier such as your database primary key column value (presumably you have all sorts of security as this could be dangerous).

I would change your button line to something like this:

```
"<th><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-delete" rel=" + deserializedData[i]["Id"] + ">Delete</a></th>" +
```

(Note: you have btn-default and btn-primary classes applied, but there should be only one or the other)

I have added btn-delete as a class so all of these buttons can be identified and the click event tracked. I also added a `rel` attribute with the database identifier - this will have to be changed to whatever you use.

You could then add some JavaScript to handle clicking of these buttons and the AJAX request:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".btn-delete").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/Delete",
            data: '{id: ' + $(this).attr("rel") + ' }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function() {
                alert("Deleted");
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert("Failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that it picks up the rel attribute and passes that as a paramater to the Web Method (below). It shows an alert box to indicate the status of the request.

You would need to make sure you are including jQuery before this script, of course.

Then in your ASP.NET page code behind you can create a Web Method to handle the AJAX request:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void Delete(int id)
{
    //Code to delete from database
    //If error return an exception or change method to return some value
    // for error which you can show to the user
}
```

For further examples see http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx as I copied a bit of code from there for my answer.